# Pinout for EA-X40027AR

Tags: datasheet, pinout, character-lcd

Can anyone show me a pinout for the Character LCD EA-X40027AR from EPSON?

I've already found a [datasheet](http://www.dougrice.plus.com/hp/LCDdata/pdfs/EA-Xspec.pdf) but it has no pinout...

Answer (score 1):

There are pinouts on both page 13 and 31 of the Data Sheet you link to. All you need is identify pin 1. From memory (I have used these devices, like 15 years ago), its pad is clearly different from the others.

Comment: Thanks... But I read the whole thing!?

Comment: Found it? It really is where I said.

Comment: fgrieu is correct, page 13 "III-A Input/Output Terminal Configurations" has the 2x9 connector pinouts listed in a table. The left half of the table lists the odd-numbered row of pins, and the right half of the table lists the even-numbered row of pins. Page 31 scale drawing of the assembly is the drawing where I would expect to see the pin 1 location called out, along with the same terminal configuration table. In this case, you will have to look at the board to locate pin 1. Typically Pin 1 is identified by a square pad while the other pins have round pads.